# Problem with Erf near Infinity in NSolve

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I have to solve a differential equation involving the error function `Erf`, but my code is not able to evaluate it in the range I need.

I think I can formulate my problem in the following simplified terms: let's consider the following functions

```
VV[x_]:=Exp[-2 x^2]
cc[x_]:=Erf[x]-1 

f[r_]:=cc[r^-2]/Sqrt[cc[r^-2]^2 + (1 + r) VV[r^-2]^2]
```

I have to evaluate the function `f[r]` for small values of `r`. However, for `r<.2` I get the following message

```
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered"
```

due to the presence of error functions. I tried to increase the precision but without success.

Do you have any suggestions to overcome this problem? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try `cc[x_] := -Erfc[x]` instead.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will try immediately

Comment: Indeed, it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large $x$, the value of $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ approaches $1$, so even if you were able to evaluate it you would encounter a [catastrophic loss of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) when you subtracted $1$ from it.

For this reason, implementations typically also provide the complementary function
$$\operatorname{erfc}(x)=1-\operatorname{erf}(x)$$
designed to provide better precision in these situations. Thus you can define

```
cc[x_] := -Erfc[x]
```

and everything works:

```
VV[x_] := Exp[-2 x^2]

(* bad *)
cc[x_] := Erf[x] - 1
f[r_] := cc[r^-2]/Sqrt[cc[r^-2]^2 + (1 + r) VV[r^-2]^2]

(* good *)
cc2[x_] := -Erfc[x]
f2[r_] := cc2[r^-2]/Sqrt[cc2[r^-2]^2 + (1 + r) VV[r^-2]^2]

Plot[{f2[r], f[r]}, {r, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Automatic}]
```

[image]

If you wanted to evaluate $\operatorname{erf}(x)+1$ for large *negative* $x$, you would have the same problem because $\operatorname{erf}(x)\to-1$ as $x\to-\infty$, and then you would want to use
$$\operatorname{erf}(x)+1=-\operatorname{erf}(-x)+1=\operatorname{erfc}(-x)$$
instead.

Comment: Many thanks, your explanation is extremely clear and the problem is now solved.